# Image are being uploaded to Cloudinary but not displaying in app (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudinary, rails-activestorage, image-upload

I am working on a Rails project hosted on Heroku with image upload via Cloudinary. The upload works, I can see the images on my Cloudinary account. In the app, the images are broken. When I copy the image address, it gives me an url starting with

`https://localhost/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWV...`

Any ideas how to solve this? I have already set `config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary` in development.rb/production.rb and set `cloudinary: service: Cloudinary` in storage.yml. The CLOUDINARY_URL is correct.

Comment: Your global app URL in the application is(maybe) `localhost`. Check your `app config vars` and see if this can solve your problem. If it doesn't work then share your config file.

Comment: I can't find anything set to localhost in the config files. Which of the files do you want to see?

Comment: Go to your app settings in the Heroku dashboard and there you will see `revel config vars`. Check your config vars and see if there is any app_url config that is pointing to the `localhost`. Have you deployed this app from some open-source project?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the config vars pointing to localhost. This was a project that was previously hosted on another Heroku account, with another Cloudinary api key, and then the images were working. After I deployed to a new account it did not work anymore

Comment: Is the code avilable somewhere?

Comment: This is what we deployed to the old account, all I changed was the cloudinary api key: [link](https://github.com/jeanmbt/artcollabs)

Comment: I don't know so much about webpack but in `webpacker.yml` the host is localhost. Can it affect?

Comment: Solved! The problem was I was using image_tag instead of cl_image_tag